# Unable to post collection data to Controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-controller

i am beginner in MVC and trying to post the collection to controller action but in controller, it is showing the count of collection=0. I've tried many different methods but no success.

I have two View Models (PatientViewModel, PatientTestViewModel) and inside patient view model, i have the collection of PatientTestViewModel named as PatientTestVM. below is the code ...

```
public class PatientViewModel
{
    private MHUContext ctx = new MHUContext();
    public patient _Patient { get; set; }
    public string MhuKey { get; set; }
    public lkp_child _LkpOccupation { get; set; }
    public List<PatientTestViewModel> PatientTestVM { get; set; }
}
```

and there is a view for PatientViewModel named as Patient.cshtml

```
@using Shared
@model Shared.PatientViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Patient";
}
<section class="well">
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreatePatient", "Patients", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "patient-main-form" }))//new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
```

...some code and then i am calling the partial view to render for the collection of PatientTestViewModel

```
<div class="accordion panel-group" id="accordion-pat-mh">
    <div class="accordion-group panel panel-primary">
        <div class="accordion-heading panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">
                <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-pat-mh" href="#mh">Medical History</a>
            </h3>

        </div>
        <div id="mh" class="accordion-body panel-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner ">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model._PatientTestVM.Count; i++)
                {
                    Html.RenderPartial("_PatientTestTile", Model._PatientTestVM[i]);
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

and here is the partial view

```
@model Shared.PatientTestViewModel
<div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 div_@(Model.PatientTestKey)">
        <div class=" form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="font-weight:normal; text-align:center;" class="control-label col-sm-10 col-md-8" for="">@Model._PatientTest.lkp_child.name</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="font-weight:normal; text-align:center;" class="control-label col-sm-10 col-md-8">@Model._PatientTest.date_created</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                    <button type="button" class="k-button k-state-default btnEdit_@(Model.PatientTestKey)">Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="k-button k-state-default btnDelete_@(Model.PatientTestKey)">Delete</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class=" form-horizontal form-widgets col-sm-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m._PatientTest.test_status)
                <span> Result Received</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

now when i submit the from, it doestn't show any record in the collection of patienttestviewmodel

```
public ActionResult CreatePatient(PatientViewModel PostedPatientVM)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

`postedPatientVM.PatientTestVM.Count = 0`

Any help/Suggestions that why this count is zero ? Please note this is the case for editing the record(and i have the data in collection, but when posting back, this data in collection becomes empty)

Comment: You cannot use a partial view (unless you pass it a `HtmlFieldPrex`). Rename your partial to `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PatientTestViewModel.cshtml` and t=in the main view use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m._PatientTestVM)` (no loop)

Comment: But your partial does not even include any form controls so there is nothing to post back anyway (so not clear what your wanting to do)

Comment: I have a form control "Check box" in the partial view,(i forgot to mention it) let me edit my question.

Comment: Based on your edit, even if you do this correctly (using an `EditorTemplate` as I noted previously), the only value you will get for `PatientTestViewModel` when you submit is `_PatientTest.test_status` (which I assume is a boolean property). I assume you will also want a hidden input for an ID property as well

Comment: @stephenMuecke thanks, by using editortemplate, it is now showing the collection of PatientTestViewModel. but there is no data inside it. i tried to checked the value of checkbox but it is showing 0 against it. any help ?

Comment: That does not make sense (it can never be `0` for a `boolean` property). Can your show the model for `PatientTestViewModel` and the model that `_PatientTest` is as well.

Comment: Thanks @stephenMuecke , it is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97866/discussion-between-abdullah-obaidullah-and-stephen-muecke).